# Is it possible to use two When statements in a Yang model

Tags: yang

Trying to use one Yang leaf with two different if-types depending on the value given.
Currently have:

```
leaf interface_number {
        when "boolean(string(/payload/interface_type) != 'ae')";
            type isyt:interface_number_value;
        when "boolean(string(/payload/interface_type) == 'ae')";
            type isyt:interface_lag_value;
        description
            "Interface Number. Example value: 1/1/1 or 11 for LAG";
        mandatory "true";
    }
```

I have also tried:

```
        leaf interface_number {
        when "boolean(string(/payload/interface_type) != 'ae')" {
            type isyt:interface_number_value;
        }
        when "boolean(string(/payload/interface_type) == 'ae')" {
            type isyt:interface_lag_value;
        }
        description
            "Interface Number. Example value: 1/1/1 or 11 for LAG";
        mandatory "true";
    }
```

Yang seems to accept the first when they errors on the second when statements' boolean.
Is this even possible? or is there a better method to use for this.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the YANG syntax works; the `type` statement cannot be conditional upon the `when`. The [`when` affects the whole enclosing node](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7950#section-7.21.5), so if it evaluates to false, your `interface_number` would not be valid at all.

What you can do here is to create a [`choice`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7950#section-7.9) whose `case` statements are `when`-conditional depending on the type of the `../interface_type` leaf. This will need a different name for each of the `leaf` that you define within these `case` statements.